# return from mergeMap in Angular 4

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular-router

I am new to Observables in Angular 4 and trying to achieve something as below

Here is my route

```
{ path: 'files', component:  FilesComponent, resolve: { files: FilesResolver }}
```

Inside my FilesResolver I have resolve method is. I call multiple service to get certain authentication token and finally make a call to httpservice (One of my services that implements HttpClient module)

```
resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot){
    this.sharedService.workspace$.mergeMap(
        workspace => {
            this.workspace = workspace;
            return this.nodeService.getNode(this.workspace.home_node_id)
        }).mergeMap(nodeData => {
            this.node = nodeData.body;
            return this.nodeService.getToken(this.node.access_key, 'user');
        }).mergeMap(tokenData => {
            this.nodeToken = tokenData.body.access_token;
            return this.httpService.get(this.node.url + 'files/' + this.workspace.home_file_id + '/files', false, null,
                {
                    'Authorization': "Bearer " + this.nodeToken,
                    'X-Aspera-AccessKey': this.node.access_key
                }
            )
        });
}
```

HttpService code

```
public get( url: string, api: boolean, authType?: string, headers?: object ) {
    return this.httpClient.get( this.makeUrl( url, api ), this.createHeaders( headers, authType ) );
}
```

And finally I subscribe in my FilesComponent as

```
constructor(
    private router: Router,
    private route: ActivatedRoute    
  ) {
    this.route.data.subscribe( data => {
      console.log(this.route);
      console.log(data);
      //this.files = data.files.body;
 });
```

My data in the `console.log` comes as `undefined`. Not able to figure out what is wrong in my `resolve` method. I need data returned from httpService get in my resolver to my component.

I am able to get all the data that is required to make the httpService get call. But when I check the networks tab, the http get call is never made. Any help here is much appreciated.

Comment: Does anything subscribe to `this.sharedService.workspace$`?

Comment: No.  I consume the `workspace` provided by the `sharedService.workspace$`

Comment: The observable will not emit until you subscribe to it. Something needs to subscribe to `this.sharedService.workspace$` ... Maybe just using `.subscribe()` at the end will work.

Comment: Adding subscribe in the end makes the http call happen. But since this is in a resolver, how do I get data in my component? (FilesComponent where I subscribe to ActivatedRoute object). I am trying to keep this code in resolver and not in Component as I plan to add to multiple resolvers to get data from couple of services in to the Component.

Comment: Actually can you just try `return this.sharedService.workspace$`?

Comment: you are not returning your observable sequence in your resolve

Comment: @ExplosionPills Thanks! I tried that too, but did not work.

Comment: so by adding the `return` statement, you now see the http calls ran? If so, are there any errors?

Comment: @LLai by adding return like `return this.sharedService.workspace$.mergeMap(` ... http calls did not run and no errors. Also how do I return observable sequence in my resolve?

Comment: You do so by returning it within your `resolve` method ([docs](https://angular.io/api/router/Resolve#how-to-use)). so like you have `return this.sharedService.workspace$...`. This tells the router what it needs to subscribe to. So this should be triggering the sequence. what is `this.sharedService.workspace$`?

Comment: `export class SharedService {
  private workspace = new Subject<any>();

  workspace$ = this.workspace.asObservable();
  
  sendWorkspace( workspace: object ) {
    this.workspace.next( workspace );
  }
}`

Comment: whenever my workspace changes, I capture that using SharedService service. And perform subsequent calls to other services from the latest workspace object.

Comment: Ah I think that is the issue. You won't get a value from a subject unless it emits after you subscribe. So the router is subscribing, but the subject never emits, causing the rest of your sequence to not run. What exactly do you need from that subject? Do you need the last value it emitted? In that case you may want a ReplaySubject

Comment: I need the workspace object from the subject So yes the last value of workspace object. I will try with ReplaySubject

Comment: try `.map(data => return data)` at the end in your resolver?

Comment: @ChauTran thanks for the comment. Not able to make it work with `.map`